# OpenLDAP Trouble Setting TLS Cipher List

Tags: ssl, ldap, tls, openldap

My institution wants to configure one of our Ubuntu servers with OpenLDAP in order to interface with our SSO provider, Okta, using a server-side agent they have for provisioning users from their cloud service to LDAP. I've been wrestling with getting our LDAP server to talk to Okta and was recently informed by one of Okta's support staff that my configuration failed because my server was sending TLSv1.1 packets and their server was responding with TLSv1.2 packets. For this reason, as well as for the security of our users, I want to force LDAP to use TLSv1.2 minimum, however, when I attempt to use ldap_modify with the following ldif file:

```
dn: cn=config
add: olcTLSCipherSuite
olcTLSCipherSuite: ALL:!TLSv1:TLSv1.2:TLSv1.3:!NULL
```

LDAP throws the error:

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "cn=config"
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
```

I get the same error even with simpler cipher-lists like:

```
olcTLSCipherSuite: ALL
```

I believe my SSL is properly configured and seems to be running (i.e. I can connect to it externally with OpenSSL) and my certificates are identified as follows:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ldap/sasl2/my-ldap.crt

replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ldap/sasl2/my-ldap.key
```

and the openldap user has read access to all of them.

I'm at a loss for where to go from here and don't know LDAP nearly well enough to make an educated guess about what is happening. I'd be more than grateful for any recommendations anyone can provide! I have LDAP's logging enabled at (-1) and will dump some of the output from the ldap_modify command below.

```
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: #011#011one value, length 32
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: conn=1017 op=1 MOD dn="cn=config"
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: conn=1017 op=1 MOD attr=olcTLSCipherSuite
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: => access_allowed: result not in cache (olcTLSCipherSuite)
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: => access_allowed: add access to "cn=config" "olcTLSCipherSuite" requested
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: => acl_get: [1] attr olcTLSCipherSuite
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: => acl_mask: access to entry "cn=config", attr "olcTLSCipherSuite" requested
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: => acl_mask: to value by "gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth", (=0)
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: <= check a_dn_pat: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: <= acl_mask: [1] applying manage(=mwrscxd) (stop)
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: <= acl_mask: [1] mask: manage(=mwrscxd)
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: => slap_access_allowed: add access granted by manage(=mwrscxd)
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: => access_allowed: add access granted by manage(=mwrscxd)
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: slap_queue_csn: queueing 0x7f58dc103a30 20200213194727.142704Z#000000#000#000000
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: oc_check_required entry (cn=config), objectClass "olcGlobal"
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: oc_check_allowed type "objectClass"
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: oc_check_allowed type "cn"
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: oc_check_allowed type "olcArgsFile"
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: oc_check_allowed type "olcPidFile"
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: oc_check_allowed type "olcTLSCACertificateFile"
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: oc_check_allowed type "olcTLSCertificateFile"
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: oc_check_allowed type "olcTLSCertificateKeyFile"
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: oc_check_allowed type "olcToolThreads"
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: oc_check_allowed type "structuralObjectClass"
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: oc_check_allowed type "entryUUID"
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: oc_check_allowed type "creatorsName"
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: oc_check_allowed type "createTimestamp"
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: oc_check_allowed type "olcLogLevel"
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: oc_check_allowed type "olcTLSCipherSuite"
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: oc_check_allowed type "entryCSN"
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: oc_check_allowed type "modifiersName"
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: oc_check_allowed type "modifyTimestamp"
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: send_ldap_result: conn=1017 op=1 p=3
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: send_ldap_result: err=80 matched="" text=""
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: send_ldap_response: msgid=2 tag=103 err=80
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: conn=1017 op=1 RESULT tag=103 err=80 text=
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: slap_graduate_commit_csn: removing 0x7f58dc103a30 20200213194727.142704Z#000000#000#000000
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: daemon: activity on:
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]:  12r
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]:
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: daemon: read active on 12
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: connection_get(12)
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: connection_get(12): got connid=1017
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: connection_read(12): checking for input on id=1017
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: op tag 0x42, time 1581623247
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: ber_get_next on fd 12 failed errno=0 (Success)
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: daemon: epoll: listen=9 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: connection_read(12): input error=-2 id=1017, closing.
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: daemon: epoll: listen=10 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: connection_closing: readying conn=1017 sd=12 for close
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: daemon: activity on:
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: connection_close: deferring conn=1017 sd=12
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]:
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: conn=1017 op=2 do_unbind
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: conn=1017 op=2 UNBIND
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: connection_resched: attempting closing conn=1017 sd=12
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: daemon: epoll: listen=9 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: connection_close: conn=1017 sd=12
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: daemon: epoll: listen=10 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: daemon: removing 12
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: daemon: activity on 2 descriptors
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: daemon: activity on:
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]:
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: conn=1017 fd=12 closed
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: daemon: epoll: listen=9 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Feb 13 14:47:27 poster slapd[20666]: daemon: epoll: listen=10 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
```

Comment: Here is another question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51745010/ldap-modify-other-e-g-implementation-specific-error-80). It that case the order matters.

Comment: I saw those and had tried grouping the olcTLSCipherSuite configuration with the Certificate configs but didn't have any luck. I could try other orderings of those but without a clear idea of what the ordering should be I feel like a bit like I'm blindly guessing for the correct option. If ordering is the problem hopefully someone can help clarify what the ordering should be for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh. The problem was that I was using OpenSSL syntax for the CipherSuite attribute and not GnuTLS syntax. Although I had tried GnuTLS before there must have been a typo that prevented it from loading into the config the first time and left me convinced that that wasn't the issue (i.e. my entire experiencing learning LDAP lol). The .ldif configuration that ended up working was:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcTLSCipherSuite
olcTLSCipherSuite: SECURE256:+SECURE128:-VERS-TLS-ALL:+VERS-TLS1.2:+VERS-DTLS1.2:-RSA:-DHE-DSS:-CAMELLIA-128-CBC:-CAMELLIA-256-CBC
```

which was the recommended spec from the [RHEL TLS hardening guide found here.](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-hardening_tls_configuration)